# Why is my keycode test giving me undefined in canvas game?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Working on my first game ever, I can't get my player to move, as I can't get the keys (left and right arrow) to register correctly.  When I alert (e.keycode) and push the left or right key, I get "undefined".  These keys are the left and right arrow on the tutorial I'm watching.  I just wanna see my little square move!

```
var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src = "zombie.png";

var mapArray =
       ["############################",
        "#      #    #      o      ##",
        "#                          #",
        "#   ####   #####    ##     #",
        "##         #   #    ##     #",
        "###           ##     #     #",
        "#           ###      #     #",
        "#   ####          ###      #",
        "#   ##    #  o             #",
        "# o  #    #    o ###   ### #",
        "#    #    #                #",
        "############################"];

//need to add wall.scource =  and grass.source =
var wall = new Image();
var grass = new Image();
grass.src = "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/tibia/images/6/60/Grass_(Tile).gif/revision/latest?cb=20080817072800&path-prefix=en";
wall.src = "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/74/37/22/74372202cfd397f5fbd004fc45d83ca3.jpg";

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

context.rect(posX, posY, 50, 50)
context.stroke();//traces path, might not need this


function move(e) {
    alert(e.keycode);//gives feedback to what each keydcode is, but doesn't work
    if (e.keycode == 39) {
        posX += 5;
    }
    if (e.keycode == 37) {
        posY += 5;
    }
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    context.rect(posX, posY, 50, 50)
    context.stroke();
}


    document.onkeydown = move;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('myCanvas');` to `var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');`. JavaScript is case-sensitive. `keycode` should be `keyCode`.

Comment: I don't think I can.  Getting rid of it messes up my context variable